# With the new Unearthed Arcana on Barbarians, if you are conscious but at 0 HP do hits still give you auto failed death saves?

Tags: dnd-5e, barbarian, hit-points, rage, unearthed-arcana

> Beginning at 14th level, the divine power that fuels your rage allows you to shrug off fatal blows. While raging, having 0 hit points doesn’t knock you unconscious. You still must make death saving throws, and you suffer the normal effects of taking damage while at 0 hit points. However, if you would die due to failing death saving throws, you don’t die until your rage ends.

From the new [barbarian Unearthed Arcana](https://media.wizards.com/2016/dnd/downloads/UA_Barbarian.pdf). Would the normal rule of being hit while at 0 hp give you automatic death saving throw failures even though you are conscious?

Answer (score 23):

Automatically failing a death save doesn't depend on you being conscious or not, it depends on you having 0 HP.

> **Damage at 0 Hit Points.** If you take any damage while you have 0 hit points, you suffer a death saving throw failure.

<sup>PHB, pg.197.</sup>

And the Rage Beyond Death ability states:

> you suffer the normal effects of taking damage while at 0 hit points.

Automatically failing a death saving throw is a normal effect of taking damage while at 0 hit points so yes, that rule still applies even though you are conscious.

Answer (score 3):

> you suffer the normal effects of taking damage while at 0 hit points

... is pretty clear. If the hit doesn't kill you from massive damage it is a failed death save, or 2 for a critical hit.